laravel 11 cannot save and upload the image
i am a beginner of laravel.i am creating a simple form along with image uploading.when i fill the form and select the image and upload image not uploading and data not saved in the databases.what i tried so far i attached below please check the code and get the solution.
here is the code of form
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('car.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                @csrf
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label>Car title</label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="title" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Car title">
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="description" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Description">
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                        <label>Model</label>
                        <select name="model_id" id="model_id" class="form-control">
                            @foreach($carmodels as $id => $name)
                                <option value="{{ $id }}">
                                 {{ $name }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>



                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                        <label>Member</label>
                        <select name="member_id" id="member_id" class="form-control">

                            @foreach($members as $id => $name)
                                <option value="{{ $id }}">
                                 {{ $name }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        </div>


                        <div class="mb-3">
                        <label>Fuel Type</label>
                        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option selected>Open this select</option>
                        <option value="1">Diesel</option>
                        <option value="2">Patrol</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>


                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label>Year</label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="year" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="year">
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label>Mileage</label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="mileage" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Mileage">
                        </div>



                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label>Price</label>
                            <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="price" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Price">
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label>Photo</label>
                            <input type="file"  class="form-control" name="photo" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Photo">
                        </div>

                
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-2">Register</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

store function
 public function store(Request $request)
{


    // Validate the incoming request data
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'model_id' => 'required',
        'member_id' => 'required',
        'fuel_type' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'mileage' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048', // Adjust file size and allowed extensions as needed


    ]);

    // Check if the file was uploaded successfully
    if ($request->hasFile('photo'))
     {
        $fileName = $request->file('photo')->store('images', 'public');

        // Save the product with the file name
        $validatedData['photo'] = $fileName;




    }
    // Create a new Car record in the database using the validated data
    Car::create($validatedData);
    // Redirect the user back to the previous page
    return redirect()->back();
}
}

routes
Route::post('storecar', [CarController::class, 'store'])->name('car.store');
Route::get('allcar', [CarController::class, 'index']);


Share route defination for the store(Request $request) . what errors/logging details you are getting during form submit?

i wrote the route above can you check it

no error i am getting.....

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

i am not getting any error i checked the laravel log

laravel 11 record are not  saved and  image upload not working

@VasanthaKalyani , Have you imported this use Illuminate\Http\Request; to the top of the CarController ?

here : <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Car;
use App\Models\CarModel;
use App\Models\Member;   i already done

add this https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors to your blade to show validation error and stop using chat gpt...

You're missing the name attribute on the fuel type select input. Without this, Laravel won't be able to capture the value.
Update Fuel Type Select:
<div class="mb-3">
  <label>Fuel Type</label>
  <select class="form-select" name="fuel_type" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected>Open this select</option>
    <option value="1">Diesel</option>
    <option value="2">Petrol</option>
  </select>
</div>


thanks sir you help.......................................................

you're very welcome
